# How to retrieve the total number of bytes read and written on the boot drive

Tags: objective-c, c, macos, unix, system

```
io_iterator_t drives = IO_OBJECT_NULL;
mach_port_t masterPort = IO_OBJECT_NULL;

IOMasterPort(bootstrap_port, &masterPort);
IOServiceGetMatchingServices(masterPort, IOServiceMatching(kIOBlockStorageDriverClass), &drives);

io_registry_entry_t drive = 0;
uint64_t totalBytesRead = 0;
uint64_t totalBytesWritten = 0;

while ((drive = IOIteratorNext(drives)))
{
    io_name_t drivePath;
    IORegistryEntryGetPath(drive, kIOServicePlane, drivePath);
    NSLog(@"Path:%s", drivePath);

    NSNumber* statVal = 0;
    NSDictionary* statistics;

    statistics = (NSDictionary*)IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(drive, CFSTR(kIOBlockStorageDriverStatisticsKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, kNilOptions);

    if (statistics)
    {
        statVal = (NSNumber*)[statistics objectForKey:(NSString*)CFSTR(kIOBlockStorageDriverStatisticsBytesReadKey)];
        totalBytesRead += [statVal intValue];

        statVal = (NSNumber*)[statistics objectForKey:(NSString*)CFSTR(kIOBlockStorageDriverStatisticsBytesWrittenKey)];
        totalBytesWritten += [statVal intValue];
    }

    [statistics release];
    IOObjectRelease(drive);
}
IOIteratorReset(drives);

readRate = (double)(totalBytesRead - prevReadVal)/1024;
writeRate = (double)(totalBytesWritten - prevWriteVal)/1024;

prevReadVal = totalBytesRead;
prevWriteVal = totalBytesWritten;
```

I am trying to retrieve the total number of bytes read and written on the boot drive since startup. However, the above code doesn't seem to work. I did a little investigation and realised that the line: `statistics = (NSDictionary*)IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(drive, CFSTR(kIOBlockStorageDriverStatisticsKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, kNilOptions);` is not working. Instead of returning a valid object, the function seems to return null. Does anyone know why? A comprehensive google search did not yield any results.

Note I am on Mountain Lion OS X using objective C and building an app for OSX.

Comment: Odds are good the block storage driver just doesn't support this property. IOKit's funny like that. If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish, we may be able to suggest an alternate approach.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I am trying to retrieve the number of bytes that have been written and read from the boot drive.

Comment: Yes, but why? How is that information of value to you? What do you plan to do with that information?

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan I am trying to create a type of activity monitor. Not having this info is not an option.

Comment: Well, odds are good you can't get the info. Sorry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I retrieve read/write disk info?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962296/how-can-i-retrieve-read-write-disk-info)

Comment: Jonathan is quite likely right, but there is one almost surefire way to know (for any given release, anyway).   The source for just about everything below the GUI layer is available for any given release of the OS.   You could peruse the IOKit sources relevant to this question and determine what metrics might be available.  http://opensource.apple.com